# Replacement for Deprecated jMonkey methods

Tags: deprecated, jmonkeyengine

I am currently working through the [jMonkey beginner tutorials](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3), specifically [Hello Collision](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3abeginner%3ahello_collision) and have ran across a deprecated class in the tutorial, [CharacterControl](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/bullet/control/CharacterControl.html).  I found what seems to be the most natural successor [BetterCharacterControl](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/javadoc/com/jme3/bullet/control/BetterCharacterControl.html).  I have been able to modify the tutorial code to get it to compile and run but the "character", i.e. the first-person perspective, does not seem to move when i use the specified key bindings.  I'm pretty sure that the issue is that i am not setting up the player correctly.  here are the old lines of code from the tutorial..

```
CollisionShape sceneShape =
        CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape((Node) sceneModel);
landscape = new RigidBodyControl(sceneShape, 0);
sceneModel.addControl(landscape);

CapsuleCollisionShape capsuleShape = new CapsuleCollisionShape(1.5f, 6f, 1);
player = new CharacterControl(capsuleShape, 0.05f);
player.setJumpSpeed(20);
player.setFallSpeed(30);
player.setGravity(30);
player.setPhysicsLocation(new Vector3f(0, 10, 0));
```

and here is what i changed it to..

```
com.jme3.bullet.collision.shapes.CollisionShape sceneShape = 
    CollisionShapeFactory.createMeshShape((Node) sceneModel);
landscape = new RigidBodyControl(sceneShape, 0);

player = new BetterCharacterControl(1.5f,6f,1);
player.setJumpForce(new Vector3f(5f,20f,0f));
player.setGravity(new Vector3f(0f,10f,0f));
player.warp(new Vector3f(0,30,0));
```

1) for some reason i had to add the full class name for `CollisionShape` even though i am importing it earlier in the file, if anyone knows why that would be great but not a huge issue right now

2) i tried to find the most analogous methods that i could but as you can see, even though the naming is similar for some they take different arguments.  I looked though the documentation but it is pretty sparse as far as explaining what each method etc actually does/is used for

3) the only other place that i changed code is in the update loop.  i changed this..

```
cam.setLocation(player.getPhysicsLocation());
```

to this...

```
cam.setLocation(player.getViewDirection());
```

which doesnt seem to have caused any problems, the camera still moves as normal (atleast when standing still and panning around. as i said i havent been able to move at all)

if anyone has experience with jMonkey im sure this isnt too complicated...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the somewhat late response (only by 2 months...),

Are you adding the BetterCharacterControl to the PhysicsSpace? It doesn't seem that you are, and I believe that if it's not in the physics space, the changes you make won't be applied, so movement wouldn't actually move it.

Try that, maybe? Assuming you haven't fixed it/given up already?